# Establecer created_by en createview con usuario del modelo de Django

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

Estoy montando una aplicación y ya he llegado al punto de dar de alta objetos y me he encontrado con un problema.

La aplicación es un ERP para registrar actividad para el control de proyectos.

El Funcionamiento que necesitaría:

Por un lado, en el momento de crear un registro nuevo, en el combobox del formulario recoger solo las funciones (contenedor) en que la fecha closed_at>=hoy. Esto debería de estar con la línea:

```
self.fields["function_id"].queryset = Functions.objects.filter(closed_at__gte=datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
```

Por otro, para los campos excluidos (*_by y *_at) necesitaría que se establecieran en base al momento de crear el registro.

Para los campos *_at lo debería de tener con el parámetro default establecido en la declaración del campo en el modelo.

la gran duda y aquí es donde me vuelvo loco, por un lado como recojo el self.request.user en el formulario y por otro como atribuyo el valor

Mi código tal y como lo tengo actualmente :

views.py

```
@method_decorator(login_required(login_url='/login/'), name='dispatch')
class ActivitiesCreateView(CreateView):
    # specify the model for create view
    model = Activities
    template_name = 'sox/activities_new.html'

    fields = '__all__'
    #fields = 'code', 'name', 'description'

    def get_success_url(self):
        return f'/success/{self.object.pk}/'

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        form_kwargs = super(ActivitiesCreateView, self).get_form_kwargs()
        form_kwargs.update({"request": self.request})
        return form_kwargs

def ActivitiesCreateFunction(request):
    form = ActivitiesFormCreate()
    return render(request, 'sox/activities_new.html', {'form': form})
```

models.py

```
class Activities(ExportModelOperationsMixin('Activities'), models.Model):
    function_id = models.ForeignKey(Functions, verbose_name='Función', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,
                                   related_name='activity_function')
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name='Usuario', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,
                                   related_name='activity_user')
    activity = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Actividad', blank=False, unique=False, default=0,
                                help_text='Actividades en SLA')
    sla = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='SLA', blank=False, unique=False, default=0,
                                help_text='Actividades FUERA de SLA')
    hours = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Horas', choices=hours, blank=False, unique=False, default=0,
                                help_text='Horas')
    minutes = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Minutos', choices=minutes, blank=False, unique=False, default=0,
                                help_text='Minutos')
    comment = models.CharField(verbose_name='Comentario', max_length=800, blank=False, unique=True,
                                   help_text='Máximo 800 caracteres.')
    date = models.DateField(default=timezone.now, verbose_name='Fecha Imputación', blank=False, unique=False,
                                  help_text='Fecha Imputación')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, verbose_name='Creado el ', blank=True, unique=False)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name='Creado por', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True,
                                   unique=False, related_name='activity_created_user')
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, verbose_name='Actualizado el ', blank=True, unique=False)
    updated_by = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name='Actualizado por', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True,
                                   unique=False, related_name='activity_updated_user')
    closed_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, verbose_name='Cerrado el ', blank=True, unique=False)
    closed_by = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name='Cerrado por', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True,
                                  unique=False, related_name='activity_closed_user')

    @property
    def time(self):
        return self.hours + (self.minutes / 60)

    historical = HistoricalRecords()

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.function_id}' + ' -|- ' + f'{self.user_id}' + ' -|- ' + f'{self.activity}' + ' -|- ' + \
            f'{self.hours}' + ' -|- ' + f'{self.comment}'

    def toJSON(self):
        item = model_to_dict(self)
        return item

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Actividad'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Actividades'
        ordering = ['function_id', 'user_id']
```

forms.py

```
class ActivitiesFormCreate(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ActivitiesFormCreate, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields["function_id"].queryset = Functions.objects.filter(closed_at__gte=datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))

    class Meta:
        model = Activities
        exclude = ('user_id','created_by','created_at','updated_by','updated_at','closed_by','closed_at')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.request = kwargs.pop("request", None)
        super(ActivitiesFormCreate, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

template.html

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <!-- Security token -->
    {% csrf_token %}

    <!-- Using the formset -->
    {{ form.as_p }}

    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Mil gracias!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

A falta de respuestas seguí investigando más y finalmente di con la solución.

Para establecer datos para los campos ocultos/excluidos de un formulario la forma más sencilla de realizar es haciendo uso del método `form_valid`

```
    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user_id = self.request.user
        form.instance.created_by = self.request.user
        form.instance.updated_by = self.request.user
        form.instance.closed_by = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Quedando en su totalidad de la siguiente manera:

```
@method_decorator(login_required(login_url='/login/'), name='dispatch')
class ActivitiesCreateView(CreateView):
    # specify the model for create view
    form_class = ActivitiesFormCreate
    model = Activities
    template_name = 'sox/activities_new.html'

    def get_success_url(self):
        res = reverse('sox:activities_list')
        if 'page' in self.request.GET:
            res += f"?page={self.request.GET['page']}"
        return res

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user_id = self.request.user
        form.instance.created_by = self.request.user
        form.instance.updated_by = self.request.user
        form.instance.closed_by = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```